# How to enable Only Numeric Digit Keyboard ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am working on ios app current I m facing the problem. I have three text fields and I want from the user to give numeric digit input in these fields i.e 1 2 3 etc.but in Numeric keypad there is also an option for Arabic digits . is there any way to remove Arabic digit option from keypad?

Comment: Are you using the phone pad keyboard?

Comment: No, you cannot do anything other than setting the keyboard type to numberpad or phonepad. The other digits you see are there because of device's regional setting which you cannot control.

Comment: @Fogmeister no i m using number pad

Comment: I can’t look properly at the moment but google UIKeyboardType. There are several number pad options the provide different sets. Give them a try.

Comment: you could use yourTextFieldName.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardTypePhonePad.

Comment: @Malleswari i tried but not working for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this function in delegate method.

```
 public static func convertStringtoArabic(_ paramString: String) -> String {
    var finalString: String = paramString
    finalString = finalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "٠", with: "0")
    finalString = finalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "١", with: "1")
    finalString = finalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "٢", with: "2")
    finalString = finalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "٣", with: "3")
    finalString = finalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "٤", with: "4")
    finalString = finalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "٥", with: "5")
    finalString = finalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "٦", with: "6")
    finalString = finalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "٧", with: "7")
    finalString = finalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "٨", with: "8")
    finalString = finalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "٩", with: "9")
    return finalString
}
```

And Delegate Method you need to conform

```
  func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {


    var newText = NSString(string: textField.text!).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)


    newText = Preferences.convertStringtoArabic(newText)

      // You can use this new text 

    let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
    let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
    return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet)
}
```

Answer (score 39):

use this code

```
textfield.keyboardType = .asciiCapableNumberPad
```

Comment: works on iOS 10+ .. on iOS 9, it shows full keyboard with characters and digits and if you have Arabic keyboard for example, Arabic letters will appear dimmed and with english chars on top of it in a weired kinda way ..

Comment: Can also be changed from the storyboard

Comment: simple and precise answer. thanks it worked for me.

Answer (score 18):

Through Code you can do it by

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    yourTextField.keyboardType = .numberPad   //or .asciicapableNumberPad

}
```

**OR**

If you are using storyboard follow this

Change Keyboard type to Number Pad . or ascii capable Number Pad

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter) format the textual representation of cells that contain `NSNumber` objects and convert textual representations of numeric values into `NSNumber` objects. 
 You can change number formatting & style according to `Locale` also.

Function to convert any number to specific locale.

```
func numberToLocale(number : String, localeIdentifier: String) -> NSNumber?{
    let numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: localeIdentifier)
    guard let resultNumber = numberFormatter.number(from: number) else{
        return nil
    }
    return resultNumber
}
```

Call to function

```
if let number = self.numberToLocale(number: "٨٦٩١٢٨٨١", localeIdentifier: "EN"){
       print("number :", number)
}
```

Output : 86912881

Comment: Works but if your numbers starts with zero (like phone numbers or so) it won't convert them and the end result will be an invalid number unless you consider handling that in your logic

Comment: You should be able to use `minimumIntegerDigits` on `NumberFormatter` to retain leading zeroes in the string output.

Answer (score 0):

Someone Answered it in another group and it works for me just don't miss to set "yourTextField.delegate = self" in your viewDidLoad

---

It Shows Arabic Keyboard but don't worry when you start typing it's converting automatically all arabic digits into English one and you can see it by your self also in the screen when you start typing ✅

---

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if textField.keyboardType == .numberPad && string != "" {
            let numberStr: String = string
            let formatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "EN")
            if let final = formatter.number(from: numberStr) {
                textField.text =  "\(textField.text ?? "")\(final)"
            }
                return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).