# How do I convert Arabic numbers to English numbers?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITextField and most users have an Arabic and English keyboard in there iPhones. My problem is when I type Arabic number in my text field the app crashes but when I enter an English number everything works just fine!

My code:

```
func plussNumbers() {
    let numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "EN") as Locale!
    var englishString = numberFormatter.number(from: "١")
    englishString = "1"

    textlable.numberOfLines = 0
    TextLable1.numberOfLines = 0


    if TextFailde.text == ""  {
        textlable.text! = textlable.text! + "\n"   +  TextFailde.text!
    }
    else {
        textlable.text! = textlable.text! + "\n" +  TextFailde.text!
        self.lblZeroUs.text! =  String(CInt(self.lblZeroUs.text!)! + CInt(self.TextFailde.text!)!) // i got error here
    }


    if TextFilde1.text == "" {
        TextLable1.sizeToFit()
        TextLable1.text! = TextLable1.text! + "\n"  +  TextFilde1.text!
    }
    else {


        TextLable1.text! = TextLable1.text! + "\n" + TextFilde1.text!
        self.lblZeroThey.text =  String(CInt(self.lblZeroThey.text!)! + CInt(self.TextFilde1.text!)!) // i got error here
    }

    previousValues.append(TextFailde.text ?? String(0))
    previousValues1.append(TextFilde1.text ?? String(0))
}
```

Comment: You need to tell us the complete and exact error message and point out the exact line causing the error.

Comment: @rmaddy i add picture for the problem

Comment: The string you pass to `CInt` must only contain the digits 0-9. A string with anything else returns `nil` and your misuse of `!` on optional values is causing your crashes.

Comment: @rmaddy Well, what should I do?

Comment: Use a `NumberFormatter` to attempt to convert the entered string into a number.

Comment: @rmaddy i use this code but i nothing worked `let numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en")
let englishString = numberFormatter.number(from: "١")`

Comment: Why would you set the locale to English if the text is Arabic?

Comment: @rmaddy Converting numbers from Arabic to English, because when I write the number in Arabic I get a crash

Comment: @X.BOZO: try [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49045692/1042817) to convert the number, and after it apply the operation(calculation) on it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
let numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en")
let englishString = numberFormatter.number(from: YourArabicString)
```

Example:  `arabicString = "٣"`

English string = `"3"`

Comment: but i got error `Cannot use instance member 'numberFormatter' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`

Comment: Add this method in your function.. not outside class methods

Comment: ok but when i add this code englishString = "1" i got this error

Comment: `Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'NSNumber?'`

Comment: okay.. remove this line.. englishString = "1". Your english strig already has the number in it.. you dont need to assign it to 1 again.. just use englishString as it is

Comment: Do not use `NSLocale` in Swift, use `Locale`. And the locale is `"en"`, not `"EN"`.

Comment: same problem When I write and click on the button, I get a crash

Answer (score 0):

englishString after converting from arabic number is optional need to add optional binding.

```
let numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "EN") as Locale!
if let englishString = numberFormatter.number(from: "٤") {
    print(englishString)
}
```